# Get title and buttons for the controls to the middle of this "simon says" game

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm working on a Simon Says game and I'm having problems putting the title and buttons from the bottom into the middle of the controls section. I've tried different css styles but the divs don't seem to move.

Specially, `margin-top` to move the elements closer to the middle. Right now they are at the bottom of the page. Here's what I have so far. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```css
body {
  background: url("http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/purty_wood.png");
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.simonBoard {
  margin: 0 auto;
/*   margin-top: 100px; */
  border: solid 10px black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 600px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.pad {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  z-index: 8;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.pad-green {
    background-color:#0a0;
    -moz-border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;    
}

.pad-red {
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
}

.pad-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
}

.pad-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
}

.board-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 15px solid black;
  height: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
/*   -moz-box-shadow:    -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow:         -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>SIMON</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="simonBoard">
    <div class="pad pad-green"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-red"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-yellow"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-blue"></div>   
    <div class="board-controls">
      <div class="title">SIMON</div>
      <div class="display">07</div>
      <div class="start">START</div>
      <div class="strict">STRICT</div>
      <div class="switch">ON/OFF</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: url("http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/purty_wood.png");
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.simonBoard {
  margin: 0 auto;
/*   margin-top: 100px; */
  border: solid 10px black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 600px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.pad {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  z-index: 8;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.pad-green {
    background-color:#0a0;
    -moz-border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;    
}

.pad-red {
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
}

.pad-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
}

.pad-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
}

.board-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 15px solid black;
  height: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
/*   -moz-box-shadow:    -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow:         -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>SIMON</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="simonBoard">
    <div class="pad pad-green"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-red"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-yellow"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-blue"></div>   
    <div class="board-controls">
      <div class="title">SIMON</div>
      <div class="display">07</div>
      <div class="start">START</div>
      <div class="strict">STRICT</div>
      <div class="switch">ON/OFF</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did set `.board-controls`'s `position:absolute`.

And set `.simonBoard`'s `position:relative`.

I think it is not good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it by adding another div inside your board-controls div.

As follows -

```
 <div class="board-controls">
   <div class="control-menu">
     <div class="title">SIMON</div>
     <div class="display">07</div>
     <div class="start">START</div>
     <div class="strict">STRICT</div>
     <div class="switch">ON/OFF</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and then add the following css -

```
.control-menu {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:50%;
}
```

This will make the new control-menu div a section in its own right and then the absolute positioning will try and pull it in each direction, therefore making it sit centrally inside the board-controls.

You can adjust the height that the menu sits using the height percentage in the supplied css.

Here is a JSFiddle displaying it working.

https://jsfiddle.net/jvshu3du/1/

Answer (score 1):

As each div are nested you could either individually declare and style that or you have to change positioning of `.simonBoard` to `relative` and inside `.board-controls` to `absolute` then using `top`, `left` and `translate` you can align `.simonBoard` to center of page and same `.board-controls`.

```css
body {
  background: url("http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/purty_wood.png");
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.simonBoard {
  border: solid 10px black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 600px;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.pad {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  z-index: 8;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.pad-green {
  background-color: #0a0;
  -moz-border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;
}

.pad-red {
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
}

.pad-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
}

.pad-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
}

.board-controls {
  border: 15px solid black;
  height: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  /*   -moz-box-shadow:    -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow:         -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); */
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}

.title {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>SIMON</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="simonBoard">
      <div class="pad pad-green"></div>
      <div class="pad pad-red"></div>
      <div class="pad pad-yellow"></div>
      <div class="pad pad-blue"></div>   
    <div class="board-controls">
      <div class="title">SIMON</div>
      <div class="display">07</div>
      <div class="start">START</div>
      <div class="strict">STRICT</div>
      <div class="switch">ON/OFF</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the main issue is you are not *clearing* the `float`s that you are applying to the four `pad` divs. That is why when using *floating containers*, it is always said that we should properly `clear` the floats. The rest is easy.

1. Clear float by giving `clear: both` to the `board-controls`.
2. Now add `position: relative` to `simonBoard` and center the `board-controls` using this:

   ```
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   ```

   (the queer thing is that clearing floats doesn't matter now though as you are using `absolute` *position*, but you should be doing it)
3. Now center the divs inside the `board-controls` by using `line-height` if you'd like that:

   ```
   .board-controls > * {
      line-height: 45px;
   }
   ```

See demo below:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/purty_wood.png");
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.simonBoard {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 10px black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 600px;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  position: relative;
}

.pad {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  z-index: 8;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.pad-green {
  background-color: #0a0;
  -moz-border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 300px 0 0 0;
}

.pad-red {
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 300px 0 0;
}

.pad-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 300px;
}

.pad-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 300px 0;
}

.board-controls {
  border: 15px solid black;
  height: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.board-controls > * {
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>SIMON</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="simonBoard">
    <div class="pad pad-green"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-red"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-yellow"></div>
    <div class="pad pad-blue"></div>
    <div class="board-controls">
      <div class="title">SIMON</div>
      <div class="display">07</div>
      <div class="start">START</div>
      <div class="strict">STRICT</div>
      <div class="switch">ON/OFF</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```